# Trying to assign different CSS classes to the input tag for radio buttons

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to update my website that I use for football picks.

Currently I have people submit picks via a radio survey for 16ish games.

I'm trying to replace the standard label and radio combo with an image button system. I'll have a sheet of all 32 football teams, 3 images for each team (normal, hover, and clicked) and the CSS will draw from that file to show each button.

So my problem is I'm not sure the best way to go about this.

I was able to figure out and position one button, but will I need to assign a bunch of different classes to each team, home and away?

So far on the HTML I have:

`<input class="ARIaway" type="radio" id="game1_0" name="ARI" value="ARI">
<label for="game1"><span></span></label>
<input class="NOhome" type="radio" id="game1_1" name="NO" value="NO">
<label for="game1"><span></span></label>`

So that would be one game with ARI @ NO. The CSS I've written is:

```
input[type="radio"] {
    display:none;
}
input[type="radio"] + label span {
    display:inline-block;
    width:300px;
    height:50px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    cursor:pointer;
    background-image: url(TeamsButtons/ARIaway.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left top;
}

input[type="radio"]:hover +label span {
    background-image: url(TeamsButtons/ARIaway.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left center;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + label span {
    background-image: url(TeamsButtons/ARIaway.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    background-position: left bottom;
}
```

This code makes the ARIaway button show correctly, but I'm stuck because I'm thinking if I used a similar code for other buttons, it wouldn't work because it would apply to all input tags and they would all be competing with each other.

Would a tag like:

```
input[type="radio"][class="ARIaway"]
```

work with

```
input[type="radio"][class="NOhome"]
```

?

Comment: do you mean input.ARIaway[type="radio"] input.NOhome[type="radio"]

Answer (score 1):

Lets add a new style, say .cool radio button.

```css
input.cool[type="radio"] {
  display:none;
}
input.cool[type="radio"] + label {
 display:inline-block;
 width:300px;
 height:50px;
 vertical-align:middle;
 cursor:pointer;
 background-image: url(TeamsButtons/ARIaway.png);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: left top;

 /* dummy for testing */
 background-image: url("http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/share-sprite-new.png");
 background-color: #AAA;
}

input.cool[type="radio"] + label:hover {
 background-position: left center;
 background-color: #FAA;
}

input.cool[type="radio"]:checked + label {
 background-position: left bottom;
 background-color: #AFA;
}
```

```html
<input class="ARIaway cool" type="radio" id="game0" name="ARI" value="ARI">
<label for="game0"><span>ARIaway</span></label>
<input class="NOhome cool" type="radio" id="game1" name="ARI" value="NO">
<label for="game1"><span>NOhome</span></label>
```